# When the click textfield and open keyboard, so many error appears. Then click next, SamsungSmartSuggesti... keeps stopping appear

Tags: android, flutter, dart, textfield

I try to simple page with textfield, when I click textfield, these errors appears(If they are errors),  Flutter doctor no issues, I am working with real device,Samsung Galaxy A50 (SM-A505F),

[image]

[image]

These ones appear, when I just clicked to write texfield, then If I write, a error appears for each character

[image]

then If I click next, sometimes I don't even need to click next

[image]

[image]

LoginView, And Custom TextField,

```
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shopping/core/constants/padding/padding_constants.dart';
import 'package:shopping/core/constants/textstyle/text_styles.dart';
import 'package:shopping/core/init/translations/locale_keys.g.dart';
import 'package:shopping/product/widget/textfield/custom_textfield.dart';

class LoginView extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LoginView> createState() => _LoginViewState();
}

class _LoginViewState extends State<LoginView> {
  //Controllers
  late final TextEditingController _emailController;
  // FocusNodes
  late final FocusNode _emailFocusNode;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _emailController = TextEditingController();
    _emailFocusNode = FocusNode();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              LocaleKeys.login.tr(),
              style: TextStylesConstants.titleTextStyle,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: PaddingConstants.onlyTopSmall,
              child: Text(
                LocaleKeys.addYourDetailsToLogin.tr(),
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: PaddingConstants.onlyTopMedium,
              child: CustomTextField(
                controller: _emailController,
                focusNode: _emailFocusNode,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                hintText: LocaleKeys.yourEmail.tr(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



class CustomTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomTextField(
      {Key? key, required this.controller, this.focusNode, required this.keyboardType, required this.hintText})
      : super(key: key);
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final FocusNode? focusNode;
  final TextInputType keyboardType;
  final String hintText;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        width: context.dynamicWidth(0.9),
        height: context.dynamicHeight(0.069),
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: ColorConstants.textFieldColor,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(90),
          ),
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
            child: TextField(
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
              cursorColor: ColorConstants.brightOrange,
              cursorRadius: const Radius.circular(45),
              controller: controller,
              focusNode: focusNode,
              keyboardType: keyboardType,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: ColorConstants.textFieldColor),
                ),
                enabledBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: ColorConstants.textFieldColor,
                  ),
                ),
                hintText: hintText,
                hintStyle: TextStylesConstants.textFieldTextStyle,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/98505#issuecomment-1067976038 this one must fix SamsungSmartSugges.... keepsstopping, but rest of errors still error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TextField --> TextFormField

wrap all TextFormField with a Form and give a key

https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/validation

```
Form(
              key: formKey,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  const Text(
                    'Please log in to your account in order to interact with and create notes and talk friends',
                  ),
                  EmailTextFormField(emailController: emailController),
                  PasswordTextFormField(passwordController: passwordController),
                  LoginButton(emailController: emailController, passwordController: passwordController),
                  const ForgotPasswordButton(),
                  const SignInWithGoogleButton(),
                  const NotRegisterYetButton()
                ],
              ),
            ),
```